# How to sharpen cookie/clay cutter edge

Tags: creality-ender-3

I’m new to 3D printing and have the Creality Ender 3 Pro. I work a lot with clay for earrings and wanted to design my own cutters with a sharp edge to create clean shapes.

I use PLA and have been using the speed and nozzle (0.4 mm) that was already set when I bought it. It’s been creating fine edges but I’d like to make it a lot sharper. Using the instructions from videos I saw online, I created the following "U" shape (extrusion of .5 mm Is the “cutting edge”. I started getting some weird bubbles too and am not sure what has created that either (see pic).

I use Fusion 360 to make the cookie/clay cutter and then send it to Ultimaker Cura to slice.

Any help with how to make it sharper and more clean cuts would be great!

[image: Cookie/clay cutter form]

Comment: my wife have the exact same problem, did you found a way to fix this problem?

Answer (score 3):

An extrusion width of 0.5 mm is too wide for making a sharp outline, I do use this sometimes for extrusion width for the infill.

Note that you can sand plastic (e.g. PLA or ABS) to sharpen the edge.

Answer (score 1):

To build in 0scar's answer, standard nozzle width is 0.4 mm, so using a width of 0.5 mm will likely make the slicer extrude the edge as *two extrusion lines*, either with one of them very thin (which is hard to print precisely), or overextruded so that the total width is closer to 0.8 mm. You should probably aim for exactly the nozzle/line width, or since that sometimes causes slicing problems due to numerical inaccuracy, something like 5% over, with the slicer's "minimum flow" set to 10% or more so that a second line does not get laid down at all. You could also try reducing the line width below the nozzle width. Down to about 75% of the nozzle width should work pretty reliably; below that it's likely to have problems.

Aside from that, your print seems to have a lot of blobs and extrusion errors on it. To make this work well, you should try to find the causes of those issues too and get them fixed.